# How can I put my name and address at the bottom of the first page?

Tags: footnotes

In an article, I want to put, at the bottom of the first page, my references (name, laboratory, email...) but I do not know how to do so.

Comment: Perhaps just a footnote will work for you.

Comment: Which class are you using? `amsart` has `\thanks{}` and also `\address{}`.

Comment: @Sigur -- yes, `amsart` has `\address`, but all addresses are set at the end of the article, not at the bottom of the first page.  but `\thanks` (which produces an unnumbered first-page footnote) could be persuaded to do what is asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `fancyhdr` package for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{My name, my laboratory, my email ...}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```